# Duda sobre uso de Printf en Java

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar, y tengo un ejercicio que me piden lo siguiente. Básicamente tengo que imprimir en pantalla este texto de abajo con `printf` pero no sé ni por dónde empezar.

`<br> El valor de la variable casado es true </br>
<br> El valor de la variable MAXIMO es 999999 </br>
<br> El valor de la variable diasem es 1 </br>
<br> El valor de la variable diaanual es 300 </br>
<br> El valor de la variable miliseg es 1298332800000 </br>
<br> El valor de la variable totalfactura es 10350,677734 </br>
<br> El valor de la variable totalfactura en notación científica es 1.035068E+04 </br>
<br> El valor de la variable poblacion es 6775235741 </br>
<br> El valor de la variable sexo es M </br>`

He estado buscando información en Internet acerca de cómo utilizar la clase `printf` pero mi nivel de programación es tan bajo que no entiendo bien tampoco las explicaciones y no sé cómo hacer el ejercicio. ¿Alguien me puede explicar qué reglas he de seguir para utilizar `printf` para sacar en pantalla lo que me pide el ejercicio? Muchas gracias.

Comment: [aqui explican bien el uso de printf](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2012/08/java-printf.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("Texto que deseas imprimir");
```

Para imprimir texto plano. Si quieres pasar una variable e imprimirla te dejo este ejemplo:

```
double n = 1.25036;
System.out.printf("%.3f %n", n);
```

Salida:

```
1,250
```

Answer (score 0):

Desglosando un poco más la respuesta que da @walter-cordova, la función `System.out.printf()` se define de la siguiente manera `System.out.printf(String format, Object...args)`, es decir una función que recibe como primer parámetro el formato de despliegue para el `stream` de salida y en segundo lugar los datos correspondientes a dicho formato.

Ejemplo práctico:

```
double x = 1.00001;
char y = 'A';
int z = 13;
String s = "Otro String";

System.out.printf("Esta es una salida con printf donde x: %.3f,%n //%n representa un salto de línea
    y: %c, z: %d",x,y,z);
System.ou.printf("Este es otro String s: %s",s);
```

Resultado:

```
Esta es una salida con printf donde x: 1.000, 
y: A, z: 13
Este es otro String s: Otro String
```

En resumen, en lugar de concatenar datos en un String gigante, `System.out.printf()` te permite dar formato a tu salida y asignar los valores correspondientes a los *"tokens"* seleccionados.

Importante recordar que existen *"tokens"* específicos para el formato de  cada tipo de dato.

Visita este enlace https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html para una explicación más técnica del funcionamiento de `format` y para consultar la tabla de `flags` y `converters` o *"tokens"* permitidos.

Aquí https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Summer16/resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf un ejemplo igual de digerido que el proporcionado por @luis-fernando